# How to add link in a Cognito Forms label

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to add a link on one of the labels but can't find a way to do this. For example I have added a checkbox saying 'I accept the terms' and I want to link the 'terms' text to my terms page.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

While you cannot add a link to a Label or Helptext for a field, you can add a Content field above or below your Checkbox field, which can include information about the Terms and a link to them.